# If f is measurable, then the inverse image is also measurable...

Tags: real-analysis

> Let the function f be defined on a measurable set E. Then f is measurable if and only if for each open set O, the inverse image of O under f, $f^{-1}(O) = \{x \in E | f(x)=0\}$, is measurable

Proof:

> If the inverse image of each open set is measurable, then since each interval $(c,\infty)$ is open, the function f is measurable. Conversely, suppose f is measurable. Let O be open. Then we can express O as the union of a countable collection of open, bounded intervals $\{I_k\}^{\infty}_{k=1}$ where each $I_k$ may be expressed $B_k \cap A_k$, where $B_k = (-\infty b_k)$ and $A_k = (a_k, \infty)$. Since f is a measurable function, each $f^{-1}(B_k)$ $f^{-1}(A_k)$ are measurable sets. On the other hand, the measurable sets are a $\sigma-algebra$ and there $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable since $f^{-1}(O)$ = $f^{-1}[\cup^{\infty}_{k=1} B_k \cap A_k]$ = $\cup^{\infty}_{k=1} f^{-1}(B_k) \cap f^{-1}(A_k)$.

My question:

Instead of saying "Let O be open. Then we can express O as the union of a countable collection of open, bounded intervals..." and "Since f is a measurable function, each $f^{-1}(B_k)$ $f^{-1}(A_k)$ are measurable sets." Why can't we just say "Since f is a measurable function, $f^{-1}(O)$ is a  measurable set." In other words, why do we need to break O up into pieces?

Comment: What is the definition of "measurable function" that you are using?

Comment: @wj32 Our textbook says that "A set E is said to be **measurable** provided for any set A, $m^*(A) = m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^c)$". But it also says that any interval is measurable...and since O is an interval or the union of intervals, is it not automatically measurable?

Comment: @Artus wj32 asked for your definition of measurable **function**, not measurable **set**. It is a very helpful comment.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Oh, ok thanks...we know that $f^{-1}(B_k)$ and $f^{-1}(A_k)$ are measurable, because they are they are part of the domain, which needs to be measurable, right? But I have one more question. Let's say that $f(x)=x^2+2$. Since O can be any open interval, if we choose it to be $(0,\infty)$...then what is $f^{-1}((0,1))$? Because we know that the function doesn't exist there, right?

Comment: @Artus Your definition of the inverse image of $f$ is not quite right. It should say $f^{-1}(O)=\{x\in E\,|\, f(x)\in O\}$.